# Some inputs coming from matrices and others from vectors, how to replace 2d loop?

Tags: r

I have a function which I would rather not edit. Some inputs are time dependent (shown here as vectors), some are time dependent and also dependent on another variable, Nj.

I'm currently looping over time (Ni) and looping over Nj and calculating each value individually. As far as I can see, the apply family of functions only work in this scenario when all inputs have the same dimensionality. Is there another way that I can do this?

```
Ni <- 10
Nj <- 10

a <- matrix(1:100/100, Ni, Nj)
b <- matrix(runif(100)*500, Ni, Nj)
c <- runif(Ni)
d <- c + runif(Ni)
e <- runif(1)*100
f <- c(0.3, 0.7)

funky <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

  firstLine <- a / b
  secondLine <- firstLine * c
  thirdLine <- (secondLine + 45) / d
  fourthLine <- thirdLine + e
  result <- c(f[1] * fourthLine, f[2] * fourthLine)

  result

}

resultMatrix1 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)
resultMatrix2 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)

for (i in 1:Ni) {
  for (j in 1:Nj) {

    result <- funky(a[i, j],
                    b[i, j],
                    c[i],
                    d[i],
                    e, 
                    f
    )

    resultMatrix1[i, j] <- result[1]
    resultMatrix2[i, j] <- result[2]
  }
}
```

This is some made up code I just threw together that shows what I mean about the input dimensions. The issue is that the actual function I'm using isn't very fast and the actual result grid I'm filling is around 100*150 and it takes about half an hour to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vectorize one of the loops. I will vectorize the `for` loop on `i`.

```
set.seed(1234)

Ni <- 10
Nj <- 10

a <- matrix(1:100/100, Ni, Nj)
b <- matrix(runif(100)*500, Ni, Nj)
c <- runif(Ni)
d <- c + runif(Ni)
e <- runif(1)*100
f <- c(0.3, 0.7)

funky <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

  firstLine <- a / b
  secondLine <- firstLine * c
  thirdLine <- (secondLine + 45) / d
  fourthLine <- thirdLine + e
  result <- c(f[1] * fourthLine, f[2] * fourthLine)

  result

}

resultMatrix1 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)
resultMatrix2 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)

for (i in 1:Ni) {
  for (j in 1:Nj) {

    result <- funky(a[i, j],
                    b[i, j],
                    c[i],
                    d[i],
                    e, 
                    f
    )

    resultMatrix1[i, j] <- result[1]
    resultMatrix2[i, j] <- result[2]
  }
}

resultMatrix1
resultMatrix2


funky2 <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {

  firstLine <- a / b
  secondLine <- firstLine * c
  thirdLine <- (secondLine + 45) / d
  fourthLine <- thirdLine + e
  result <- matrix(c(f[1] * fourthLine, f[2] * fourthLine), ncol = 2)

  result
}

rmat <- array(NA, dim = c(2, Ni, Nj))
for(j in 1:Nj) {
  result <- funky2(a[, j], b[, j], c, d, e, f)
  rmat[1, , j] <- result[, 1]
  rmat[2, , j] <- result[, 2]
}


identical(resultMatrix1, rmat[1, , ])
#[1] TRUE
identical(resultMatrix2, rmat[2, , ])
#[1] TRUE


JoePye <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj){
  resultMatrix1 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)
  resultMatrix2 <- matrix(numeric(), Ni, Nj)

  for (i in 1:Ni) {
    for (j in 1:Nj) {

      result <- funky(a[i, j],
                      b[i, j],
                      c[i],
                      d[i],
                      e, 
                      f
      )

      resultMatrix1[i, j] <- result[1]
      resultMatrix2[i, j] <- result[2]
    }
  }

  list(Mat1 = resultMatrix1,
       Mat2 = resultMatrix2)
}
RuiB <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj){
  rmat <- array(NA, dim = c(2, Ni, Nj))
  for(j in 1:Nj) {
    result <- funky2(a[, j], b[, j], c, d, e, f)
    rmat[1, , j] <- result[, 1]
    rmat[2, , j] <- result[, 2]
  }
  rmat
}

library(microbenchmark)

mb10 <- microbenchmark(
  JoePye = JoePye(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj),
  RuiB = RuiB(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj)
)
mb10
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
# JoePye 473.950 479.2840 496.5165 483.6325 495.7015 758.162   100   b
#   RuiB 150.502 157.8205 174.8730 160.1100 165.2400 647.653   100  a
```

This is a speed up by a factor of 3.
Now test with bigger input.

```
set.seed(1234)

Ni <- 1e2
Nj <- 2e1

a <- matrix(seq.int(Ni*Nj)/100, Ni, Nj)
b <- matrix(runif(Ni*Nj)*500, Ni, Nj)
c <- runif(Ni)
d <- c + runif(Ni)
e <- runif(1)*100
f <- c(0.3, 0.7)

res1 <- JoePye(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj)
res2 <- RuiB(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj)

identical(res1[[1]], res2[1, , ])
#[1] TRUE
identical(res1[[2]], res2[2, , ])
#[1] TRUE


mb100 <- microbenchmark(
  JoePye = JoePye(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj),
  RuiB = RuiB(a, b, c, d, e, f, Ni, Nj),
  times = 10
)
mb100
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
# JoePye 9198.846 9248.114 9421.2359 9352.244 9426.161 10147.642    10   b
#   RuiB  478.564  490.404  533.8198  522.573  594.841   602.938    10  a
```

And with bigger input the speed up factor went up to a factor of 18.